# Issues in sending email with multi lingual context in html file

Tags: java, email, smtp, multilingual, mime

I am using the basic approach to send an email via SMTP using,

http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-in-html-format-using-javamail-api

This works perfectly fine for english but when I insert some text of a different lanuage like

> ಹಾಯ್ ಇಲ್ಲ

I receive an email with context

> ????? ??????????

I have tried converting the text to UTF-8 but it does not work. 
Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set/declared non US-ASCII charset in `setContent`?

```
message.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Extra suggestion: It may help to [declare utf-8 encoding in html](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp) too.

Comment: I added a multipart "alternative" and attached a body part with the above-mentioned solution. It works. Thanks